# Changing datatype of an entire column with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table (sqlite db) with a column as below:

```
XO_HOUSE_NUMBER
95.0
10.0
63.0
6.0
```

The house numbers are in decimals and I would like them to be in integers. So when I cast so,

```
session.query(Policies.XO_HOUSE_NUMBER.cast(sql.Integer)).limit(10).all()
```

I get the correct output:

```
[(95,), (10,), (63,), (6,), (55,), (1,), (19,), (1,), (30,), (21,)]
```

Now I would like to update this column in with the casted values. So I tried three analogous ways:

```
1.
session.query(Policies).update({Policies.XO_HOUSE_NUMBER: Policies.XO_HOUSE_NUMBER.cast(sql.Integer)}, synchronize_session=False)
2.
session.execute(update(Policies, values={Policies.XO_HOUSE_NUMBER: Policies.XO_HOUSE_NUMBER.cast(sql.Integer)}))
3. 
session.query(Policies).update(values={'XO_HOUSE_NUMBER': Policies.XO_HOUSE_NUMBER.cast(sql.Integer)}, synchronize_session=False)
```

each time getting the same output in py terminal

> 119752

Then `session.commit()`
But the values are not updated, they remain in decimals. I am doing something wrong, what can I do to update the entire column with non-decimal i.e. integer values using ORM method?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is that changing types is not possible via SQLAlchemy. SQLAlchemy cannot execute `ALTER` commands. The easiest way is to execute the command directly in the db